# Extracting metrics key as value

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Extracting values from my printer using prometheus-snmp-exporter I get the following values to be displayed in grafana:

```
usageTonerCurrentLevel{instance=xxxx,usageTonerCurrentLevel="70",usageTonerIndex="3"} 1
```

Is there an easy way (using grafana) to transform these values that I get "70" from the key extracted to be used as the real value (would be best, if this ends up in a time series).

Comment: Prometheus doesn't support converting label into variable. And generally, if you end up wanting this, means you messed up on the instrumenting the code. But I don't know if exposing data in any other way is possible with snmp-exporter.

Comment: On the other hand, I think it is possible to make Grafana treat this a value. If(!) you found that exposing this metric in a "proper" way is not possible, I'd try querying current metric as Table(switch under query in panel edit) and then applying one of the Transformations that change type of the column. I think this should be enough for most panels.

Comment: @markalex Sorry for not putting grafana in there, fixed that.

Comment: You tagged question with grafana, so it's not a problem. Also I shortly looked into snmp exporter and I think you should be able to change your configuration there to expose percentage as an actual metric value.